# How to disable screen in Commodore 64?

Tags: c64, commodore, 6510

I know this question is very spesific question but I know there are some c64 code gurus around here. So, here is my question.

When I try to disable screen using $d011 trick, upper/lower border also opens. I want to do that without opening upper/lower borders. Is it possible?

Comment: Ah, the system that put me where I am today.  Thank you Commodore!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Oh, a c64 question. Nice. :) I have one sample in my code archive. You need to do the $d011 trick at the beginning of the screen, not at the end.

This is an ACME source code.

```
    !to "nobadlines.prg",cbm

!macro WAIT .v {
    ldy #.v
    dey
    bne *-1
}

    * = $0801
    !byte $0c, $08, $00, $00, $9e, $32, $30, $36, $31, $00, $00, $00

    * = $080d
    lda #$01
    sta $3fff
    sei
start:
    lda #$30
    cmp $d012
    bne *-3
    lda #$00
    sta $d011
    +WAIT 24
    lda #$0b
    sta $d011
    lda #$31
    cmp $d012
    bne *-3
    lda #$1b
    sta $d011
    +WAIT 8
    bit $ea
    ldx #$00
loop1:
    txa
    sta $d020
    sta $d021
    +WAIT 9
    inx
    cpx #254
    bne loop1
    asl $3fff
    bne start
    inc $3fff
    jmp start
```

Comment: I am not using ACME but I successfully converted it to my asm editor. It works and exactly what I was looking for! Thanks so much Emir.